# How are extremely high/low temperatures achieved on Earth?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

Low Temperature Superconductors (LTS) have their critical temperature below 30K.

**How are they cooled to such low temperatures?**

The operating temperature of a [tokamak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokamak) is greater than 10 keV (over 100 million degrees Celsius).

**How is this operating temperature achieved?**

Comment: What research have you done?  If you had investigated cryogenics, you would know that temperatures much lower than 30 K are regularly achieved.  Ditto for tokamaks.

Comment: @user16622 I know the temperatures are regularly achieved. I'm asking how

Comment: Do the basic research I recommended and come back with specific questions.

Comment: @user16622 This is a specific question. I am asking what the methods are called wherby such temperatures can be achieved in order to research about them.

Comment: Relevant: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uh-e4UFwzqE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have reached temperature as low as 0.00000001K in the lab and as high as millions of degrees in a nuclear bomb.

We achieve such low temperatures by using different techniques. [Laser cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_cooling) is one of them. In laser cooling, where we fire photons in a certain direction which are accepted and reemitted by atoms in such a way that they retain a component of velocity in a certain direction only. This happens for many atoms and ultimately we have an orderly motion of atoms which don't contribute for temperature calculations (temperature is a measure of unorderly motion of particles).

[Magnetic Refrigeration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_refrigeration) is another popular method used to produce liquid nitrogen and helium.

We can achieve very high temperatures using [laser heating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusion_power#Inertial_confinement_fusion). The idea of using lasers to increase the temperature to millions of degrees is already being used in fusion reactors (experimental reactors). The idea is to fire concentrated laser beams at a point to increase the temperature. The matter exists in the plasma state in such high temperatures and we make use of strong magnetic fields to confine the plasma to a region.